# Extruding faces along normals to do a roll

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image: What I called the Roll]What's the best way to extrude the selected faces (along the normals) on the car seat to do the roll?

How to extrude the faces normal to them and then once normal to one side, and then in the opposite direction to make something like on the picture but following the seat edge?
I thought about Shrink/fatten but it does not work.

[image: Racing car seat]

Comment: Not sure that's what you mean but try extruding with E, right click or Esc to cancel movement, then Alt+S to scale along normals (shrink/fatten)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> to extrude towards the mouse. (if you are talking about making the curved back)

[image: animated gif - ctrl click to extrude]

---

If you are just trying to make the edge rounded (a Subsurf modifier will help will the smooth roundness) add an edge loop on the out side edge. The pink line in the image below is the new edge loop.
[image: new edge loop on edge of seat mesh]

Then switch the *Transform Orientation* to *Normal* and move the new edge along the normal Z.

[image: animated gif - adding the new edge loop and then moving it in to place to make the rounded edge]

Comment: Thank you very much but that's not what  I want to get. I added a picture to help. I extruded E than cancel and alt-S. It's OK.